# Cannot Install Remote Desktop Services dismapi_error__failed_to_enable_updates rds-web-access

Tags: windows, remote-desktop-services, windows-server-2019

I am having trouble installing Remote Desktop Services after upgrading from Server 2012 to Server 2019. I had Remote Desktop Services installed on 2012, but the rds-web-access role was not functioning. I tried to remove all remote desktop roles and start over, but the rds-web-access roles keeps failing when I try to install using Install-WindowsFeature RDS-Web-Access -IncludeAllSubFeature:

> - Install-WindowsFeature RDS-Web-Access -IncludeAllSubFeature
> - ```
>   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (@{Vhd=; Credent...Name=localhost}:PSObject) [Install-WindowsFeature],
>   Exception
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DISMAPI_Error__Failed_To_Enable_Updates,Microsoft.Windows.ServerManager.Commands.AddWind
>   owsFeatureCommand
>   ```

I have tried the following:

- Installing with Server Manager GUI
- DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
- DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:wim:D:\sources\install.wim:1 /limitaccess
- sfc /scannow
- Install-WindowsFeature RDS-Web-Access -source D:\sources\install.wim

Each time I am met with the above error. sfc /scannow keeps telling me that it found corrupted files and have successfully repaired them, even when I run sfc /scannow right after it claims to repair them, it tells me that it found corrupted files again.

The last few entries on my cbs log after attempting to install rds-web-access look like this: https://pastebin.com/GANeWPzd

The only way I got the install to succeed is if I install "Install-WindowsFeature RDS-RD-Server -IncludeAllSubFeature" before I install the rds-web-access role. If I do that though it requires a reboot and the install fails during the reboot and it will revert the changes.

Everything else, including Windows Updates, seems to be working fine. Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Is that post could help ?, https://serverfault.com/questions/524762/cannot-install-rds-web-access if yes we can mark as a duplicate

Comment: I found this thread. The answers did not help me.

Comment: A guess, but I seen IIS error in the cbs log, as the default web site exist, can you make sure the IIS role is not installed before installing the RDWeb component ?

Comment: You want me to try uninstalling the IIS roles before installing rdweb?

Comment: Yes if you can, I dont know what the IIS role host on your server

Comment: Disregard my last comment. It successfully installed RemoteApp, but did not install remote web access. Remote web access still fails.

Comment: Does that changed the cbs log ?

Comment: No, unfortunately it appears that it reports the same thing to the CBS log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by performing a clean install of IIS using the steps in this guide:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2017/01/16/how-to-perform-a-clean-reinstallation-of-iis/

I then had to delete the URL acl. You can view your acls with this command:

> netsh http show urlacl

And delete:

> netsh http delete urlacl http://+:80/
>   netsh http delete urlacl https://+:443/